# Copying Excel Spreadsheet with Absolute Hyperlinks to Documents (change to relative?)

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, hyperlink

I have a large spreadsheet created in Excel 2010 with nearly 100 pdf and word documents hyperlinked in hundreds of cells.

I had planned to copy the folder the spreadsheet is in - which contains the documents the hyperlinks point to - to multiple flash drives to give to co-workers.

Except every time I move it, the links look for the absolute reference and not the relative reference.

Can anyone help? I've been hunting for a macro that could convert all the hyperlinks from absolute to relative, but I can't find anything. Actually, I can't find any way to just keep the hyperlink from becoming an absolute hyperlink.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Yes, someone can help, but you need to give some more details in order for that to happen. 1) What have you tried? 2) How were the hyperlinks created? 3) Can you give us an example of one of the hyperlinks? 4) Have you read [this Microsoft support article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/328440)?